# Как объединить две таблицы?

Tags: sql

Как объединить две таблицы и сгрупировать результат по полю средствами sql запросов?

Есть две таблицы.

Код создания первой:

```
CREATE TABLE [prihod] (
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  [d] INTEGER, 
  [m] VARCHAR(20), 
  [y] INTEGER, 
  [point] VARCHAR(80), 
  [predprijatie] VARCHAR(80), 
  [title] VARCHAR(80), 
  [prihod] CURRENCY, 
  [n_m] INTEGER);
```

Код создания второй:

```
CREATE TABLE [rashod] (
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  [d] INTEGER, 
  [m] VARCHAR(20), 
  [y] INTEGER, 
  [point] VARCHAR(80), 
  [predprijatie] VARCHAR(80), 
  [title] VARCHAR(80), 
  [rashod] CURRENCY, 
  [n_m] INTEGER);
```

Эти таблицы надо объединить в одну и сделать группировку по полю [m] средствами sql запроса. Как это сделать?

Comment: Код надо форматировать кнопкой 101010.

Comment: возможно стоит посмотреть в сторону [**MERGE**](ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL))

Answer (score 5):

Ну `UNION` же и `GROUP BY`

---

Конкретнее, полагаю, вы хотите что-то такое (сложить приходы и вычесть расходы по месяцам):

```
select m, sum(prihod) from
    (select m, prihod from prihod
    union
    select m, -rashod from rashod) t
group by t.m
```

Answer (score 2):

**day** - `INTEGER`, 
**month** - `VARCHAR(20)`, 
**year** - `INTEGER`,

Вероятно это дата, не забудьте и по этим полям сделать группировку.

Да, и со структурой таблиц надо разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM prihod pr
INNER JOIN rashod ra ON (pr.m = m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если прям одним запросом, то можно использовать подзапросы для группировки данных перед `JOIN`, но данное решение не очень хорошее, на больших объемах данных будет долго выполняться.

```sql
SELECT `prihod`, `rashod`, `m`, `y`
FROM (SELECT `m`, `y`, sum(`prihod`) AS prihod FROM prihod GROUP BY `m`, `y`) AS p
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT `m`, `y`, sum(`rashod`) AS rashod FROM rashod GROUP BY `m`, `y`) AS r
ON p.`m` = r.`m` AND p.`y` = r.`y`;
```

Правильных решений я вижу 2:

1) Самое правильно объединить эти две таблицы в одну (сущность то одна и та же). И запрос будет простой и работать будет быстрее

```sql
CREATE TABLE `accounting` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `val` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

2) Агрегировать данные и сохранять во временную таблицу, у вас же за прошлые периоды не будут данные добавляться и обновляться? Тогда запрос будет выглядеть так:

```sql
SELECT `prihod`, `rashod`, `m`, `y`
FROM prihod_by_month AS p
FULL OUTER JOIN rashod_by_month AS r
ON p.`m` = r.`m` AND p.`y` = r.`y`;
```